# Erase Metal Texture [iOS]

Tags: ios, metal

How can I erase a Metal texture that was drawn to the screen using the following blending parameters and pipeline descriptor? By “erase”, I mean to fill with the clear color.

**Blending parameters:**

```
renderPipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].isBlendingEnabled = true
renderPipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].rgbBlendOperation = .add
renderPipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].alphaBlendOperation = .add
renderPipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].sourceRGBBlendFactor = .one
renderPipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].sourceAlphaBlendFactor = .one
renderPipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].destinationRGBBlendFactor = .oneMinusSourceAlpha
renderPipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].destinationAlphaBlendFactor = .oneMinusSourceAlpha
```

**Pipeline descriptor:**

```
descriptor.colorAttachments[0].loadAction = .load
descriptor.colorAttachments[0].clearColor = MTLClearColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha:0.0)
descriptor.colorAttachments[0].storeAction = .store
descriptor.colorAttachments[0].texture = colorAttachmentTexture

let renderCommandEncoder = commandBuffer.makeRenderCommandEncoder(descriptor: descriptor)
renderCommandEncoder?.setRenderPipelineState( blendRGBAndAlphaPipelineState)
texturedQuad.encodeDrawCommands(encoder: renderCommandEncoder!, texture: texture)
renderCommandEncoder?.endEncoding()
```

I tried changing the sourceRBGBlendFactor and sourceAlphaBlendFactor to .zero, but this did not create the desired erase effect.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "erase"? Just fill with the clear color? Restore what was there before the recent drawing? Please clarify.

Comment: Yes, by erase I meant to fill with clear color.